# Ci andiamo a vedere un film?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

In comune all'inglese, "guardare" è una forma che implica un'attenzione maggiore rispetto a "vedere". Il caso più diffuso è quello della televisione:

> Io sto guardando la televisione.

Infatti, "vedere" produrrebbe una diversa interpretazione rispetto a quella intesa.

Tuttavia, non utilizzerei mai "guardare" piuttosto che "vedere" nel caso di una proiezione cinematografica:

> Andiamo a <s>guardare</s> vedere un film al cinema.

Questo è strano perché, del resto, in inglese il verbo "watch" verrebbe utilizzato dato che si tratta di un'osservazione prolungata nel tempo, equivalente a quella di un programma televisivo che richiederebbe anche meno sforzo, se vogliamo.

Perché dunque è [comune usare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vedere+un+film%2C+guardare+un+film&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvedere%20un%20film%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cguardare%20un%20film%3B%2Cc0) questa formazione?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La forma *"andiamo a vedere"* è usatissima per indicare un'attività di svago/turismo che si svolge in un altro posto in cui si *va* e consiste nell'assistere a qualche forma di spettacolo o ammirare monumenti o paesaggi.

EDIT: Come giustamente sottolinea @DaG, è molto vero anche che "guardare" tende ad essere usato quando è in corso l'azione "meccanica" e istantanea di *guardare* e il film sta scorrendo nel proiettore.

Quando il film è stato *visto* per intero, interiorizzato e ricordato come una cosa unitaria si preferisce, appunto, "visto".

Pertanto, si dice "andiamo a *vedere* il Colosseo", si dice "andiamo a *vedere* la partita", "andiamo a *vedere* Arma Letale", ma una volta che si è già *dentro* la sala cinematografica, si dice "sto guardando il film" (e "sto guardando la partita"); una volta usciti si dice di nuovo "abbiamo visto Arma Letale" (oppure: "è scoppiato un incendio mentre stavamo guardando il film e ci hanno fatto uscire").

Analogamente per ascoltare/sentire: "andiamo a sentire il concerto di Maurizio Pollini?" vs. "sto ascoltando il concerto".

Nota che il "*ci*" in "*ci* andiamo a vedere un film", come titola il tuo post originale, benchè ammissibile in un contesto informale, non è particolarmente standard ma non è in questo senso determinante.

Comment: Sì, ma... Anche in altre costruzioni si tende a usare “vedere” ben più spesso che “guardare”, detto di un film. Pensa a “ieri ho visto un film” o “è un po' che non vedo nessun bel film”, per non parlare poi di quando si menziona un titolo specifico: “hai visto *Fast & Furious 7*?” Nessuno direbbe “hai guardato *F&F7*?”. O c'è qualcosa che mi sfugge nel tuo ragionamento?

Comment: Hai molta ragione, ho aggiornato la risposta.