# What is the difference between guardare and vedere

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

Eg: "mi piace guardare la gente".
I used *vedere* in this sentence but it was marked wrong. I'd like to know the difference between the two.
There are some explanations online but it is in Italian and my Italian is not that good.
http://www.skuola.net/grammatica-italiana/vedere-guardare-differenze.html

Comment: As a first approximation, you use *guardare* when in English you'd use “to look at” or “to watch”, and *vedere* when in English you'd use “to see”.

Comment: Related question (in Italian): http://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5367/707.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from idiomatic structures (such as the suggested "Vedere gente"), it's a bit like in English:

- Guardare = Look (at)
- Vedere =  See

"You *saw* something happens because you were *looking* in its direction"
= "*Hai visto* succedere qualcosa perche' *stavi guardando* in quella direzione"

"I *have seen* a nice exhibition at the museum, but I think the guard *was looking* at me suspiciously" = "*Ho visto* una bella mostra al museo, ma credo che la guardia *mi guardasse* con sospetto"

Answer (score 3):

Italian has the idiom *vedere gente* which can be translated into *meet with people*. The sentence *mi piace vedere la gente* is, at least, incomplete, if not wrong; on the other hand,

> mi piace vedere la gente che fa festa

is good.

Both *guardare* and *vedere* have a meaning connected to sight. The sentence *mi piace guardare la gente* means you like to look at people, independently on what they do. Using *vedere* requires you realize what those people are doing and decide you like it. This is because *vedere* implies more involving an action than simply *guardare*.

See [Ci andiamo a vedere un film?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5367/707) for other details.